# Which one is the right method of initializing a NSMutableDictionary . Please anyone correct me here

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I am trying to create a NSMutableDictionary in my class. I have read many post in stackoverflow to understand the difference. But now i am totally confused. So any one correct me , which one is the correct way of initialing a NSMutableDictionary in my class . I have to access this dictiionary in many areas of my application .So suggest me the good way of using the variable initialization ...

```
/// .h file
@interface ActiveFeeds : NSObject {

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *invDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *filePath;
@end

@implementation ActiveFeeds

@synthesize filePath;
@synthesize invDictionary;

- (id)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.filePath];
        self.invDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
         dictionary release]; 
    }
    return self;
}

/* And use self.invDictionary all in the application */
- (void)setObjectAtKey:(NSMutableDictionary *)objectDic atKey:(NSString *)setKey{
    [self.invDictionary setObject:objectDic forKey:setKey];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.invDictionary release];
    [self.filePath release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

or like this ....

```
@interface ActiveFeeds : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *invDictionary;
    NSString *filePath;
}
@end


@implementation ActiveFeeds

- (id)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            invDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
            [dictionary release];
        }    
    }
    return self;
}

/* And use invDictionary all in the application */
- (void)setObjectAtKey:(NSMutableDictionary *)objectDic atKey:(NSString *)setKey{
    [invDictionary setObject:objectDic forKey:setKey];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [invDictionary release];
    [filePath release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Please any one help me to get the correct way of using the variables ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithFilePath:(NSString *)path{

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
       self.filePath = path;
       self.invDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

also

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [invDictionary release];
    [filePath release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: so which interface are you trying to point. If i initialize like this , how i will call in '- (void)setObjectAtKey' and '- (void)dealloc ' .....

Comment: [instance setObjectsAtKey:] or i don't understand you